# How to get specific columnar maximums in List of arrays?

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

I have a list "XYZarr" filled with array of integers as shown below.

```
        int[] intarr1 = new int[3]{  1, 4, 15};
        int[] intarr2 = new int[3] { 10, 5, 8};
        int[] intarr3 = new int[3] { 7, 8, 12 };
        int[] intarr4 = new int[3] { 7, 8, 9 };

        List<int[]> XYZarr = new List<int[]>() { intarr1, intarr2, intarr3, intarr4 };
```

I want to get only three indexes from  the list where int[2] is maximum(i.e third entry). so the resulting indexes should be 0,2,3 of the list "XYZarr"

I can do it by looping through the list , but i want to use LinQ for this. I am not able to phrase the question properly, but..i hope you get my point

Comment: "int[2] is maximum" compared to int[0] and int[1]? or compared to int[2] in the other arrays?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Int[2] to be compared with other arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, XYZarr.Count)
    .OrderByDescending(i => XYZarr[i][2])
    .Take(3)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: nice!! i think i will use this one :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that "int[2] is maximum" means that the 3rd element in the array is the maximum element in that array.

Here is how:

```
var result = 
    XYZarr
    .Select((list,index)
        => new {list,index})
    .Where(x => x.list.Max() == x.list[2])
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .ToList();
```

If `XYZarr` contains more than 3 arrays and you just want to get 3 results, then use the `Take` method like this:

```
var result = 
    XYZarr
    .Select((list,index)
        => new {list,index})
    .Where(x => x.list.Max() == x.list[2])
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .Take(3)
    .ToList();
```